# Product of two independent brownian motion is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Given $X, Y$ independent Brownian motions, I'd like to show that $XY$ is a martingale. This seems to be a fairly easy result, but I can't work it out, nor find anywhere that gives a proper proof.

I can see that it could be done using Ito's formula applied to $f(x,y) = xy$ but I'd like to show it directly from the martingale definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specified any filtration... I guess you talk about $\mathcal F_t=\sigma (X_t,Y_t)$.

**Hint**

Let $s<t$. You have that $$\mathbb E[X_tY_t\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[(X_t-X_s)(Y_t-Y_s)\mid \mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[(Y_t-Y_s)X_s\mid \mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[(X_t-X_s)Y_s\mid \mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[X_sY_s\mid \mathcal F_s].$$

Now, using $X_s$ and $Y_s$ are $\mathcal F_s$ measurable, $X_t-X_s$ and $Y_t-Y_s$ are independents and independents of $\mathcal F_s$, the claim follow.

Comment: You're right with the filtration, I forgot that. I see this follows easily, thank you! I just didn't quite have the right expansion.

Comment: Could you explain why $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $Y_t$ ? It's not clear for me.

Comment: @user657324 : Set $f(X_t,X_s)=X_t-X_s$ and $g(Y_t,Y_s)=Y_t$. Since $(X_t,X_s)$ and $(Y_t,Y_s)$ are independent, then so are $f(X_t,X_s)$ and $g(Y_t,Y_s)$.

Comment: Why do you consider $g(Y_t,Y_s)=Y_t$ and not $g(Y_t)=Y_t$ ?

Comment: @user657324: Because there is no reason to have $Y_t$ independent of $X_s$. The only thing I can tel is $(X_t,X_s)$ and $(Y_t,Y_s)$ are independent. But if you know that $Y_t$ and $X_s$ are also independent, then you are right, you can consider $g(Y_t)$ instead of $g(Y_t,Y_s)$.